# Django returning dictionary from front end?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm passing a dictionary from the front end to the back end in one of my Django views. The setup is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/my/url',
        data: {
            'patients': '{{ appointments.appointments.items }}'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
        success: function (data) {
              console.log("yay")
        }
      });
```

which is passing back an dictionary of names, etc. and I'm then retrieving this on the python backend, like so:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    patients = request.POST.get("patients", None)
    print("patients are", patients)
```

However, when I do this and print out the patients dict() instead of getting an actual dictionary, I get a string like this:

`dict_items([(153, {&#x27;person&#x27;: &#x27;Samuel&#x27;, &#x27;time&#x27;: datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 22, 17, 0, tzinfo=&lt;UTC&gt;), &#x27;number&#x27;: &#x27;First&#x27;})])`

that doesn't follow the dictionary format/even really allow for json parsing etc.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? The {{appointments.appointments.items}} is just passed into my HTML template page from the backend during the get request and I'm accessing it with JavaScript in the same file.

Any advice here would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to not use the `|safe` method as it still allows people to perform XSS attacks. Best is to **not render** into javascript. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67158977/14991864) of mine (I don't post it since it would just be a duplicate).

Comment: Ah cool, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think, it can be solved by adding Eval Method.

```
patients = eval(request.POST.get("patients", None))
```

Comment: Don't suggest **dangerous** things in answers when it is not needed, although `|safe` is also dangerous (potential XSS attacks) but `eval` is even more dangerous. Not to mention this won't solve the issue here.

Comment: okay @AbdulAzizBarkat, thanks for your suggestion. will it doesn't work, I would like to know why it is dangerous. can you please tell why.

Comment: `eval` allows you to execute arbitrary code. Considering this string is coming from the user the user can send just about any code here and it will be executed, **dangerous** right?