# Passing Dictionary from Views and Accessing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, django, dictionary, view

I am passing dictionary from Views in Django, and want to access in JavaScript(written in HTML)
This is my code written in HTML, here I want to access dictionary:

```
let map;
// global array to store the marker object
let markersArray = [];
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 43.8445608, lng: -79.55882869999999 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  addMarker({ lat: 43.8445608, lng: -79.55882869999999 }, "red");
  addMarker({ lat: 43.5982087, lng: -79.6252701 }, "green");
  addMarker({ lat: 43.846656, lng: -79.566523 }, "green");
  addMarker({ lat: 43.839778900146484, lng: -79.57058715820312 }, "green");
}
```

Comment: What does google maps have to do with a "dictionary" from django?

Comment: @evolutionxbox idea is that, I want to show addresses on Google maps, I am getting lat, long from addresses in views and passing that lat,long in dictionary through views to this HTML page and I want to access that dictionary in js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use python dictionary as JSON in Django template html script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67158810/unable-to-use-python-dictionary-as-json-in-django-template-html-script)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat    this is my dictionary in Views


 context = {'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude}

and this is my Code I am trying:

function initMap() {
    var lating = "{{latitude}}";
    var longin = "{{longitude}}";
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: lating, lng: longin},
    zoom: 8
  });


but not working fine